# Half Angle Identity Manipulation

Tags: trigonometry

**From website:**
[image]

**Can someone please show me how the above angles were re-stated?**

Comment: You square both sides of the first three pairs of equalities, then substitute $x$ everywhere you see $x/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $y=\frac{x}{2}$ in the initial formulas. Then for example
$$
\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}
$$
becomes (after squaring) 
$$
\sin^2(y)=\frac{1}{2}[1-\cos (2y)]
$$
The rest formula are handled in the same way.